# Placement and Opacity of tikz nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-node

I've got the following MWE, which I would like to use as a kind of road map for the defense presentation. It basically all works and looks good, but there are two things, I don't know how to fix.
The first thing is how to make the nodes appear exactly on top of each other, so as for example the starting point right of Dissertation is the same for all three paths leaving from there.
The second issue is on how to make the circle inside of each node the same opacity as the line and the fill.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\usetikzlibrary{ arrows
                , positioning
                , calc
                , arrows.meta
                , shapes
                , snakes}
\colorlet{Navyblue}{NavyBlue}
\tikzstyle{project} = [
            align=left
        %, fill=NavyBlue
        , opacity=0.2
        , text opacity=1]

\newcommand{\myopacity}{1}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.center), font=\sffamily, node distance=2cm]
\draw
  node[project,anchor=east](P) {\textbf{Dissertation}}

  node[project
        ,right= 2in of P.east
        , anchor=east
        , text opacity=0.4](P23) {}

   node[project
            , above= of P23.west
            , anchor = west
            ](P1) {\textbf{Project I:}}

   node[project
        , right = 1in of P23
        , text opacity=0.4](P2) {Project II: }
   node[project
        , below= 0.5in of P2.west
        , anchor=west
        , text opacity=0.4](P3) {Project III: }
    node[project
        , below= of P23.west
        , anchor=west
        , text opacity=0.4](P4) {Project IV:};                                                              
   % Define different colors
  \draw[{Circle[length=8pt]}-{Circle[length=8pt]}
        , line width=2pt
        , Gray
        , opacity = 0.4] (P.east) -- (P23.west);
  \draw[{Circle[length=8pt]}-{Circle[length=8pt]}
        , line width=2pt
        , darkgray
        , opacity = 0.4] (P23.east) -- (P2.west);
  \draw[{Circle[length=8pt]}-{Circle[length=8pt]}
        , line width=2pt
        , darkgray
        , opacity = 0.4
        ] (P23.east) -- (P3.west);
  \draw[{Circle[length=8pt]}-{Circle[length=8pt]}
            , line width=2pt
            , Gray
            , opacity = \myopacity] (P.east) -- (P1.west);
  \draw[{Circle[length=8pt]}-{Circle[length=8pt]}
        , line width=2pt
        , RoyalBlue
        , opacity = 0.4] (P.east) -- (P4.west);
    \draw[{Circle[length=8pt]}-{Circle[length=8pt]}
            , line width=2pt
            , Gray
            , opacity = \myopacity] (P.east) -- (P1.west);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: Screenshot of the resulting graphic]
This is the result of the proposed changes in the first comment:
[image: Result]

Comment: Instead of placing the texts in the nodes, place them as a label: `node[project,anchor=east,label={left:\textbf{Dissertation}}](P) {}` This will allow you to draw circular nodes: `\tikzset{project/.style={
            align=left
        %, fill=NavyBlue
        , opacity=0.2
        , text opacity=1
        ,draw
        ,circle}}`

Comment: Where should I put this `\tikzset` command? Does it need to go in each individual node or how do I need to incorporate it?

Comment: `\tikzset{foo/.style={...}}` does the same as `\tikzstyle{foo}=[...]`, but the latter is considered deprecated I think, so it's usually recommended to use the former.

Comment: I now got circular nodes, but they are not centered and more important next to the starting circles of the lines. Also the text opacity does not work any more on the labels and the linebreaks are gone also. I'll probably just leave it like it was before. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Labels are nodes, they have the same options as nodes and can be modified in the same way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of placing the texts in the nodes: `node[project,anchor=east](P) {\textbf{Dissertation}}`

I place them as a label. Labels are nodes, they have the same options as nodes and can be modified in the same way: `node[project,anchor=east,label={left:\textbf{Dissertation}}](P) {}`

This will allow you to draw circular nodes:

```
\tikzset{project/.style={ align=left 
                          %, fill=NavyBlue
                          , opacity=0.2 
                          , text opacity=1 
                          ,draw %draw a circle node 
                          ,circle}
                         }
```

This simplifies the line drawing code between nodes. The latter connect empty nodes and it is not necessary to specify the `P.east`, `P23.west` position or to draw their ends in a circle as: `{Circle[length=8pt]}-{Circle[length=8pt]}`

```
   \draw[{Circle[length=8pt]}-{Circle[length=8pt]}
        , line width=2pt
        , Gray
        , opacity = 0.4] (P.east) -- (P23.west);
```

The code becomes:

```
 \draw[%{Circle[length=8pt]}-{Circle[length=8pt]}
        , line width=2pt
        , Gray
        , opacity = 0.4] (P) edge (P23);
```

I commented on all the lines of code that became useless without deleting them.

I created a new node `(P23')`:

```
  node[project
        ,right= 2in of P
        %, anchor=east
        , text opacity=0.4](P23) {}
  node[project
        ,right= 10pt of P23
        %, anchor=east
        , text opacity=0.4](P23') {}
```

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\usetikzlibrary{ %arrows
                , positioning
                , calc
                , arrows.meta
                , shapes
                , snakes}
\colorlet{Navyblue}{NavyBlue}
\tikzset{project/.style={
            align=left
        %, fill=NavyBlue
        , opacity=0.2
        , text opacity=1
        ,draw
        ,circle}}

\newcommand{\myopacity}{1}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[%baseline=(current bounding box.center),
 font=\sffamily,
  node distance=2cm]
\draw
  node[project,anchor=east,label={left:\textbf{Dissertation}}](P) {}

  node[project
        ,right= 2in of P
        %, anchor=east
        , text opacity=0.4](P23) {}
  node[project
        ,right= 10pt of P23
        %, anchor=east
        , text opacity=0.4](P23') {}
   node[project
            , above= of P23
            %, anchor = west
            , label= right:\textbf{Project I:}
            ](P1) {}

   node[project
        , right = 1in of P23
        , text opacity=0.4
        ,label=right:Project II: ](P2) {}
   node[project
        , below= 0.5in of P2
       % , anchor=west
        , text opacity=0.4,label=right:Project III: ](P3) {}
    node[project
        , below= of P23
        %, anchor=west
        , text opacity=0.4
        ,label=below:Project IV:](P4) {};                                                              
   % Define different colors
  \draw[%{Circle[length=8pt]}-{Circle[length=8pt]}
        , line width=2pt
        , Gray
        , opacity = 0.4] (P) edge (P23);
  \draw[%{Circle[length=8pt]}-{Circle[length=8pt]}
        , line width=2pt
        , darkgray
        , opacity = 0.4] (P23') -- (P2);
  \draw[%{Circle[length=8pt]}-{Circle[length=8pt]}
        , line width=2pt
        , darkgray
        , opacity = 0.4
        ] (P23') -- (P3);
  \draw[%{Circle[length=8pt]}-{Circle[length=8pt]}
            , line width=2pt
            , Gray
            , opacity = \myopacity] (P) -- (P1);
  \draw[%{Circle[length=8pt]}-{Circle[length=8pt]}
        , line width=2pt
        , RoyalBlue
        , opacity = 0.4] (P) -- (P4);
    \draw[%{Circle[length=8pt]}-{Circle[length=8pt]}
            , line width=2pt
            , Gray
            , opacity = \myopacity] (P) -- (P1);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```